# How can a subversion revision in a branch be blocked from being reintegrated into the trunk?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

The team I'm on uses Subversion as its source control manager. I'd like to write up a script that will make branching feature branches easier. The logic works like this:

- Copy the trunk into a branch
- Check out branch
- Modify pom.xml to reflect that this is a branch by changing its version number, scm attributes, etc...
- Check in changes

I'd like to block that check in from reintegrating when the user eventually does a

```
svn merge --reintegrate ^my/feature/branch
```

So going off of the documentation in the [SVN red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html), I added the following step to my logic above.

- Switch to trunk
- Execute svn merge -c 1234 --record-only mybranch

Now when I attempt to catch up my branch to trunk, I get an error that says

```
svn: E195016: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 1234 through 1236 were previously merged.
```

What's worse is that if I switch back to trunk and do a merge --reintegrate, I get the change I didn't want anyway.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Despite my name being on the cover the "SVN red book", it's been a while since I using Subversion much for complicated branching and merging myself.  But I *think* the modern approach (at least as of Subversion 1.8) is to no longer use the `--reintegrate` option to `svn merge` at all, and instead just let Subversion work out the correct merge to perform.  In doing so, your so-called "blocked revision" (the one marked as already merged by virtue of the `--record-only` merge) should be omitted from the set of revisions brought back into your primary branch by the merge.

Comment: That seemed to work when it comes to merging. I suppose there's no way to catch up a branch with trunk if the trunk excludes a revision from the branch?